# While recording in Jmeter is not capturing upload the file transaction

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Is there any way to do performance testing in another tool or selenium and other frameworks. will it capturing all request like performance testing tool

Answer (score 0):

JMeter captures everything given [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) is used for file upload.

However there is one small pre-requisite. You need to **copy the file(s) you're going to upload to JMeter's "bin" folder** before recording the fil upload event.

This way JMeter will be able to properly intercept the request and generate appropriate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good tool for performance testing. ie k6. https://k6.io/.
it has a Browser Recorder extension, which can be downloaded from chrome web store.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/k6-browser-recorder/phjdhndljphphehjpgbmpocddnnmdbda